# Missing data from an 2 arm AB test and proper inference methods

Tags: modeling, inference, missing-data

Suppose in a 2 arm AB test designed to assess the increase in spend caused by a promotional offer, we randomize customers to either test or control (i.e no offer or promotional offer).

During the promotional period, some customers do not purchase anything, and so their spend is NA.  How should I analyze the data with these cases?

My gut says I should include them because of the ITT principle.  Since they have not spent any money, their spend is technically $0, which means I should maybe use some sort of hurdle model.

Furthermore, under the assumption that the offer does not change the probability of spending money, then these data would be missing completely at random.  But there is good reason to believe the offer does change the probability of spending money.

Given that the data are missing, that the ITT principle says that once a customer is randomized they should be analyzed, and that the data are not missing completely at random, how can I make inference towards the effect of the promotion on customer spend?

Comment: Can you please spell out/explain ITT?